# Why the étale cohomologies of small and big étale sites are coincide

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(Sch/S)_{et}$ be the big étale site and $S_{et}$ be the small site, the [theorem](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03YX) in StacksProject claims their cohomologies are the same, but the proof there uses many concepts like cocontinues. Are there brief ways to prove it or are there any other references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can look at the Milne book about etale cohomology. the point is that we have a natural map $f$ from sheaves on big etale site to sheaves on small etale site(restriction), which is exact because covers are the same and send Injectives
objects to acyclic object: the chech cohomology of injective object in big etale site is zero almost by definition and again because covers are the same the chech cohomology is equal in the small and the big site, hence restriction of an injective object has zero chech cohomology in the small site and it is a famous theorem that such objects are acyclic(you can see the proof in Milne book) hence $f$ of injective resolution for $F$ gives an acyclyc resolution for $f(F)$. we also by definition have $\Gamma(F)=\Gamma(f(F))$ so the cohomologies are the same.

this is the usual technique for proving equality of cohomology on two different site you have to prove that $f_{\star}$ is exact then the rest of argument work.

Comment: Thanks for your guides, I'll check Milne's book for details.